# Expected value of Kronecker product between two random matrices

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, random-matrices, kronecker-product

Let $Y$ be a $n\times p$ random matrix with expected value $\mathbb{E}(Y)=M$ and variance $\mathbb{V}(vec(Y))=V \otimes U$, with $V$ and $U$ positive semidefinite $p\times p$ and $n\times n$ matrices, respectively. I found in an article that
$$
\mathbb{E} \left(Y \otimes Y\right)= \operatorname{vec}(U) \operatorname{vec}(V)' + M \otimes M
$$
but the authors do not provide a proof and I cannot understand how this relationship can be shown. How can I calculate this exectation?

I found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3446808/expected-value-of-kronecker-product) but it involves random vectors instead of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M\equiv\mathsf{E}[Y\otimes Y]$. Then, the $((i-1)p+j)$-th column of $M$ can be written as
\begin{align}
[M]_{(i-1)p+j}&=\operatorname{vec}(\mathsf{E} [Y]_j[Y]_i^{\top})=\operatorname{vec}(\operatorname{Cov}([Y]_j,[Y]_i)+\mathsf{E}[Y]_j\mathsf{E}[Y]_i^{\top}) \\
&=\operatorname{vec}(V_{ij}U)+\operatorname{vec}(\mathsf{E}[Y]_j\mathsf{E}[Y]_i^{\top}) \\
&=[\operatorname{vec}(U)\operatorname{vec}(V)^{\top}]_{(i-1)p+j}+[M\otimes M]_{(i-1)p+j}.
\end{align}